# How to set specific property value with another property value in a javascript nested object array?

Tags: javascript, object

```
 var arr = {
    "data": [
    {
        id    : "a1",
        guid  : "sdfsfd",
        value : "abc",
        "status": "active"
      },
      {
        id    : "a2",
        guid  : "deaf",
        value : "def2",
       details : {
         "status": "inactive",
          "body": done
                  }
        "stat": "inactive"
      },
      {
        id    : "a2",
        guid  : "blind",
        value : "def4",
        details : {
           "status": "inactive",
           "body": donenot
                  }
        "stat": "inactive"
      },
    ]
      
    }
    
    console.log(arr.data.filter(item => item.stat === "inactive"))
```

***OUTPUT***

```
 [{
  details: {
    body: "done",
    status: "inactive"
  },
  guid: "deaf",
  id: "a2",
  stat: "inactive",
  value: "def2"
}, {
  details: {
    body: "done",
    status: "inactive"
  },
  guid: "blind",
  id: "a3",
  stat: "inactive",
  value: "def4"
}]
```

What if I want to set

1. The value for every such inactive status(in these 2 outputs) --> **value** property same as **guid** property...?
2. The value for every such inactive status(in these 2 outputs) --> **status** same as **body** in **details** ?

Answer (score -1):

For

1. You can do this: `arr.data = arr.data.filter(item => item.stat === "inactive").map(e => ({...e, value : e.guid}))`

OUTPUT

```
{
  data: [{
  details: {
    body: "done",
    status: "inactive"
  },
  guid: "deaf",
  id: "a2",
  stat: "inactive",
  value: "deaf"
}, {
  details: {
    body: "done",
    status: "inactive"
  },
  guid: "blind", --> same as value
  id: "a3",
  stat: "inactive",
  value: "blind"
}]
}
```

For

2. You can do this : `arr.data = arr.data.filter(item => item.stat === "inactive").map(e => ({...e, details : {...e.details, status: e.details.body}}))`

OUTPUT

```
{
  data: [{
  details: {
    body: "done",
    status: "done"
  },
  guid: "deaf",
  id: "a2",
  stat: "inactive",
  value: "def2"
}, {
  details: {
    body: "done",
    status: "done"
  },
  guid: "blind",
  id: "a3",
  stat: "inactive",
  value: "def4"
}]
}
```